# How to document what global variables are modified by a function?

Tags: c, global-variables, doxygen

What's the best way to document the fact that a function sets some global variables?  I generally prefer something that works with Doxygen as it's kind of standard and most IDEs seem to understand it, but I'm probably not going to use Doxygen to generate docs so it's not strictly necessary.

In a situation like:

```c
extern double FIRST_VALUE;
extern double SECOND_VALUE;

/**
 * Calculate the values.
 * \param input  The parameter used to calculate the values
 * \what_goes_here FIRST_VALUE
 * \what_goes_here SECOND_VALUE
 */
void calculate_values(double input)
{
    FIRST_VALUE = do_magic(input);
    SECOND_VALUE = do_more_magic(input);
}
```

(And yes, it would be nice not to use globals, but that's what I've got.)

I can put text in the detailed description, but this feels disorganized.

Comment: how about  not using global variables and instead pass them as arguments?

Comment: I'm working on an existing codebase that long predates me and is well tested.  Step 1 is to document it, not to ride roughshod over it.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Maybe use the `\post`?